# Htaccess rewrite rules with pictures

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here are my rewrite script (.htaccess)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(action|ajax|api|uploads)(.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Now I have the url: `http://domain.tld/uploads/users/1/pictures/1443563069.jpg`

The picture exist, but i can't load it. Is something with my rewrite rule not ok?

Comment: @anubhava yes 404, no i donßt think that any .htaccess is in my subdirectory, greeetings mistermm

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(action|ajax|api|uploads) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Using `%{THE_REQUEST}` because `REQUEST_URI` changes to `/index.php` in your last rule.